# UIRefreshControl isn't refreshing my XML table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uitableview

This is my first iOS app so detailed instructions on how to fix would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to implement a pull to refresh so that my XML table will refresh the data. Currently, the pull to refresh animation works, but the data does not refresh.

The support that i've received so far has not been detailed enough to help. It seems that I'm close to getting the refresh to work but I am officially stumped. An NSLog returns ...2014-02-08 11:24:58.483 MyApp [3186:70b] refreshing. Can someone paste a fix into my code? Thank you!

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
  NSXMLParser *parser;
  NSMutableArray *feeds;
  NSMutableDictionary *item;
  NSMutableString *title;
  NSMutableString *link;
  NSString *element;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib {
  [super awakeFromNib];
}

// Paste Blog feed here
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.placeholder.xml"];
  parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
  [parser setDelegate:self];
  [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
  [parser parse];
  UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
  [refreshControl addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(refresh:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
  refreshControl.attributedTitle =
  [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to refresh..."];
  self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
}

- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)sender {
  // ... your refresh code
NSLog(@"refreshing...");
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.placeholder.xml"];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  (void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

  [sender endRefreshing];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return feeds.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell =
      [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                  forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.textLabel.text =
      [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
  return cell;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
     attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

  element = elementName;

  if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
title = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
link = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

[item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
[item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];

[feeds addObject:[item copy]];
  }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

  if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
[title appendString:string];
  } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
[link appendString:string];
  }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

  [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"link"];
[[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];
  }
}

@end
```

Comment: Where is your NSURLConnection delegates ? Also you are using the same url, then how will you get different data ?

Comment: Is your code actually reaching the refresh: method? Put an NSLog there and let us know. If not, it's the refresh control issue. If the call to refresh: is made, then you have problem with your NSURLConnection method, as Midhun says. Maybe a better alternative in iOS7 is now NSURLSession with nice completion handler, so you can put all your update code there.

Comment: It's not refreshing the data. I only get the pull to refresh animation. Are you able to paste the fix into my code? Like I mentioned, this is my first app.

Comment: If you put NSLog(@"refreshing..."); right below the line // ... your refresh code, are you getting the 'refreshing...' message in console?

Comment: this is what the NSLog returned ...2014-02-08 11:24:58.483 MyApp [3186:70b] refreshing...

Answer (score 0):

This code gets triggered as soon as the user pulls-to-refresh on your tableview:

```
- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)sender {
  // ... your refresh code
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.placeholder.xml"];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  (void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

  [sender endRefreshing];
}
```

What you're doing here is telling the refresh control to end refreshing *immediately* after the user has started the refresh.

You shouldn't be invoking `-endRefreshing` until your URLConnection/parsing/refresh operation has *finished*.

Comment: So where should I move the endRefreshing to?

Comment: @user3251476 well, since you're executing a network request as part of the refresh operation, how about when your network request finishes? or if you're going to process the results of the request (parse it, whatever), you could do it when *that* finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your refresh: method with this. It's based on the new NSURLSession method and you should replace the comments in the body of the completion handler with your call to process your xml data and to update your table.

```
- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)sender
{
    // ... your refresh code
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.placeholder.xml"]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {

                // handle response
                NSXMLParser *updatedParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
                [updatedParser parse];

                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
            }] resume];
    [sender endRefreshing];
}
```

Comment: So inserting this code should correct my problem? You mention that I should replace the comments in the body of the completion handler...can you please provide more detail? Thank you very much for your assistance Martin.

Comment: I don't have experience with xml parser, but based on your code guessing just loading the data and asking to parse it again would be enough. I have updated the code.

Comment: Unfortunately that's still not working ... any other ideas? I appreciate the help.